# When should I use Neutral culture? What is the necessary for it? why not force using Specific Culture?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, currentculture, currentuiculture

When should I use Neutral culture? 
What is the necessary for it? 
why not force using Specific Culture?

Can someone tell me a real time scenario, where Neutral cultures are used than Specific Culture?

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN:

> A neutral culture is a culture that is associated with a language but not with a country or region. It differs from a specific culture, which is a culture that is associated with both a language and a country or region. For example, fr is the name for the neutral French culture, while fr-FR is the name for the French culture in France.

If this property returns false, the culture is either a specific culture or the invariant culture.

**Example**
In my case I speak Spanish from Spain however I have a friend that He speaks Spanish from Mexico. The both speak Spanish but there are some words different so if you want a good translation you should use Spanish from Spain (ES-ES) for Spanish people and Spanish from Mexico (ES-MX) for Mexican people.

In some cases you can't translate your software (GUI) to all languages and cultures so you use only a Spanish translation for all people who speak Spanish (Spain,Mexico,Argentina,USA,Philippines ...)

Comment: pls read my question.. I am not asking the difference between specific and neutral

Comment: @Rajes In the case that you create a multi language app and you don't have specific culture translations you should use neutral culture translations. 
If you speak about manage data with neutral or specific cultures, I think you should use the system current culture.